# Int as array representation

Tags: c#

I need an int array, from an int value.

> The int value 123456 converts to int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}.

Is there any better solution than this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test
{
#if DEBUG
    [DebuggerDisplay("{GetDebuggerDisplay()}")]
#endif
    public class IntArray
    {

#if DEBUG
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
#endif
        private int _value;
#if DEBUG
        [DebuggerBrowsableAttribute(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)] 
#endif
        private int[] _valueArray;

        public IntArray(int intValue)
        {
            Value = intValue;
        }

        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                _valueArray = null;
                _valueArray = CreateIntArray(value);
            }
        }

        public int[] Array
        {
            get { return _valueArray; }
        }


        private string GetDebuggerDisplay()
        {
            return string.Format("Value = {0}", Value);
        }

        private static int[] CreateIntArray(int value)
        {
            string s = value.ToString();
            var intArray = new int[s.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                intArray[i] = int.Parse(s[i].ToString());

            return intArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help and criticism would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use division and modulus?

Comment: I know about this solution but division and modulus is costly.

Comment: I would think that converting the int to a string, extracting each characters from the string, then converting each character to a string and finally parsing these strings back to integers is even more costly!  :/

Comment: Hard to imagine that division/modulus operations are more costly than converting to strings, parsing strings to integers and looping through an enumerator. And also, are you sure it is more costly than your own suggestion? It is just hard to imagine.

Comment: You are right, I tested it right now! The divison wins over linq and cast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
    public static int[] GetInts(this int value)
    {            
        if (value == 0)
            return new int[] { 0 };
        else
        {
            int val = value;

            List<int> values = new List<int>();
            while (Math.Abs(val) >= 1)
            {
                values.Add(Math.Abs(val % 10));
                val = val / 10;
            }

            values.Reverse();
            return values.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

and use it:

```
    int value = 123456;
    int[] values = value.GetInts();
```

*Edit: improved to work with negative numbers and zero*

Answer (score 4):

You can do as following using Linq. This is only the making of the array from the int value.

```
var arrayOfInts = myint.ToString().Select(i => int.Parse(i.ToString())).ToArray();
```

EDIT :
This can also be made as a [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method on int if you want to use this often.

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static int[] ToArray(this int i)
    {
        return i.ToString().Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this extension by doing this :

```
var myArray = 123456.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas! I have to say I read that and I didnt think thats what the code would do - I didnt realise that given a string the LinQ would run through the characters within it - partly I guess because I didnt think.. Dumb me. After all, its an array of characters more or less.. So, thanks.. Thats really useful to be reminded!

Comment: Glad i could assist. As the MSDN documentation states : 'Because the String class implements the generic IEnumerable<T> interface, any string can be queried as a sequence of characters'

Comment: Yep, because it was a single item, I hadnt considered it as a sequence of characters.. Its good to have that extra thought in my head for the day I decide to parse strings :) makes it easier to pull out vowls or something..

Answer (score 3):

You may convert to `int` to `String`, later you can use LINQ to Convert each character to integer and then return an array of integers using `.ToArray()`

```
int a = 123456;
string tempA = a.ToString();
int[] temp = tempA.Select(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.ToString())).ToArray();
```

EDIT: 
As per Styxxy comment:

```
    int a = 123456;
    int[] array = new int[a.ToString().Length];
    int i = array.Length - 1;
    while (a > 0)
    {
        array[i--] = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
    }
```

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, yes, but the OP didn't ask for it, and it can be done with just a check against the Absolute value. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Actually all the answers have this drawback. Forget it))

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = 123456.ToString().Select(c => Int32.Parse(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue.aspx):

```
int[] ints = 123456.ToString().Select(c => (int)char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();
```

or without Linq:

```
var chars = 123456.ToString();
int[] ints = new int[chars.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    ints[i] = (int)char.GetNumericValue(chars[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, it is better to use basic arithmetic operations, rather than converting to a string, looping through a string and parsing strings to integers.

Here is an example (I made an extension method for an integer):

```
static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static int[] ToCypherArray(this int value)
    {
        var cyphers = new List<int>();
        do
        {
            cyphers.Add(value % 10);
            value = value / 10;
        } while (value != 0);
        cyphers.Reverse();

        return cyphers.ToArray();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int myNumber = 123456789;
        int[] cypherArray = myNumber.ToCypherArray();

        Array.ForEach(cypherArray, (i) => Console.WriteLine(i));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```